# How to apply hover on the same row on two different tables?

Tags: html, css, hover, row

I have two different tables in my html, and lets assume they all have the same data collection - meaning the rows are representing the same object in the collection. I would like to apply a following functionality: when I hover on the row N in Table 1, it highlights row N in Table 1 and the same row in Table 2. I was able to get it done, however I had to manipulate my collection - I added .hover property on object, and treated it as a flag on mouse enter and mouse leave, and added specific styles according. However, I know this should not be done this way - as it breaks the two way data binding rule.

Any ideas on how I can achieve that without manipulating my data?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible with CSS alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using little jQuery:

```
var tr_class;
$('.table1 tr').hover(
  function(){
    tr_class = $('this').attr('class');
    $('this').addClass('highlightBg');
    $('.table2 ' + tr_class).addClass('highlightBg');
}, 
  function(){
   $(this).removeClass('highlightBg');
   $('table2 ' + tr_class).removeClass('highlightBg');
});
$('.table2 tr').hover(
  function(){
    tr_class = $('this').attr('class');
    $('this').addClass('highlightBg');
    $('.table1 ' + tr_class).addClass('highlightBg');
}, 
  function(){
   $(this).removeClass('highlightBg');
   $('table1 ' + tr_class).removeClass('highlightBg');
});
```

Both of your table rows need to have a class like a row number for example counting them:

```
<tr class='1'>...</tr>
<tr class='2'>...</tr>
```

.highlightBg defines a background-color for highlighted state, in this example .table1 and .table2 are the classes of the tables.

Think that should do the work.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want.but I used bit jquery with this.hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <style type="text/css">

div.tableone{
  margin:50px;
}
div.tabletwo{
  margin: 50px;
}

table{
  border:1px solid black;
}

  table tr th{
    width: 200px;
  }

  table tr td{
    text-align: center;
  }

.classOne{
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}


 </style>

   




<body>
 
 <h1>table one</h1>
  <div class="tableone">
    <table border="2">
      <thead>
        <tr class="trone">
          <th>one</th>
          <th>Two</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>dataone</td>
          <td>datetwo</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<h1>table two</h1>
  <div class="tabletwo">
    <table border="2">
      <thead>
        <tr class="trtwo">
          <th>Three</th>
          <th>Four</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>datatwo</td>
          <td>datethree</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".trone").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("classOne");
        $(".trtwo").addClass("classOne");
      });
       $(".trone").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("classOne");
        $(".trtwo").removeClass("classOne");
      });


      $(".trtwo").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("classOne");
        $(".trone").addClass("classOne");
      });

      $(".trtwo").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("classOne");
        $(".trone").removeClass("classOne");
      });


      
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem, without using jQuery, would be the following:

```
const table1 = document.getElementsByClassName("table-one")[0];
const table2 = document.getElementsByClassName("table-two")[0];

const table1Rows = table1.querySelectorAll("tr:not(.table-header)");
const table2Rows = table2.querySelectorAll("tr:not(.table-header)");

for (let i = 0; i < table1Rows.length; i++) {
  const table1Row = table1Rows[i];
  const table2Row = table2Rows[i];
  table1Row.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    table1Row.classList.add("hover-class");
    table2Row.classList.add("hover-class");
  });
  table1Row.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    table1Row.classList.remove("hover-class");
    table2Row.classList.remove("hover-class");
  });
  table2Row.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    table1Row.classList.add("hover-class");
    table2Row.classList.add("hover-class");
  });
  table2Row.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    table1Row.classList.remove("hover-class");
    table2Row.classList.remove("hover-class");
  });
}
```

Here you can see the solution in action: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pewpewz/5t8o9zc0/38/)